# Best way to extract text from a photo/image in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, ocr

I am building an app with React Native.

After a user takes a photo of an invoice, I would like to be able to extract some key data from the text in the image. I know I will need an OCR of some sort. Is there an easy solution to this? I've seen react-native-text-detector. Is that my best option? Is there a best solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `react-native-firebase-mlkit`. It has a lot more functionality than just performing OCR. It also has both on-device support and cloud based support depending on your need.

> [Here](https://github.com/mateusc42/react-native-firebase-mlkit) is the library's GitHub page.
>
> It's a wrapper for [Google's ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/)

Heres's a simple example of how to use it:

```
import RNMlKit from 'react-native-firebase-mlkit';

export class textRecognition extends Component {
  ...

  async takePicture() {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true, skipProcessing: true, forceUpOrientation: true };
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
      // for on-device (Supports Android and iOS)
      const deviceTextRecognition = await RNMlKit.deviceTextRecognition(data.uri); 
      console.log('Text Recognition On-Device', deviceTextRecognition);
      // for cloud (At the moment supports only Android)
      const cloudTextRecognition = await RNMlKit.cloudTextRecognition(data.uri);
      console.log('Text Recognition Cloud', cloudTextRecognition);
    }
  };

  ...
}
```

Comment: Is there any solution to scan non latin-based text?

Comment: @laneboyandrew Check out this link for supported languages: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/languages